# Did Schuler (Kevin Spacey's character in "Outbreak") receives the cure for the virus, or did he die?

Tags: plot-explanation, outbreak

In the film [***Outbreak***](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114069/) with Dustin Hoffman, Kevin Spacey gets infected by the virus.

Does he die?

Dustin Hoffman makes a cure but Spacey is not shown receiving it?

Comment: Sorry, don't we *see* him die?...

Comment: No we don't! We see him very ill with Renee Russo but no mention after that. I am assuming he died, hence the question

Answer (score 2):

### He dies

[**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outbreak_(film))

> On their return flight, Daniels and Salt are chased by McClintock in another helicopter, and Salt fires two rockets into the trees to trick McClintock into thinking that they crashed. In Cedar Creek, Salt mixes Betsy's antibodies with Ford's serum to create an antiserum; although **Schuler [Spacey] has died**, they save Keough.

Comment: citation needed